# Efficient count from select with fitered joins

Tags: postgresql

What would be an efficient approach in Postgres, to implementing `COUNT()` based on a `SELECT` that employs several filtered `JOIN`-s inside?

I have a `SELECT` with multiple `JOIN`-s, a set of filters and `LIMIT` + `OFFSET` to support paging logic. My client wants a `COUNT` on that too, in order to allow proper paging logic. I would prefer to avoid running the same complex query twice - once to get the data, and then the second time with a `COUNT` on top.

What would be an efficient approach in this case, for good performance, and full support of the paging logic?

The best I could come up so far was to take this original `SELECT` query:

```sql
SELECT u.id,
       org_id,
       org.name as org_name,
       r.title  as role_name,
       created,
       updated,
       login,
       u.enabled,
       forename,
       surname,
       dob,
       email,
       mobile
FROM users as u
         LEFT JOIN organizations org ON u.org_id = org.id
         LEFT JOIN roles r ON u.role = r.code
    ${filter} ${orderBy}
LIMIT ${limit} OFFSET ${offset}
```

`${filter}` is a large composite `WHERE` clause.

And condense it to the following `COUNT` version:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT org_id,
             org.name,
             forename,
             surname
      FROM users as u
               LEFT JOIN organizations org ON u.org_id = org.id
               LEFT JOIN roles r ON u.role = r.code ${filter}) AS s
```

i.e. effectively the same query, minus some columns, ordering, limit or offset. Something tells me this may be far from a good solution, considering that I'd run all the same `JOIN`-s twice, just to get the count. Or am I wrong to think so?

**UPDATE**

While there was no answer at this point, I came up with the following single-query solution:

```sql
WITH main AS (SELECT u.id,
                     org_id,
                     org.name as org_name,
                     r.title  as role_name,
                     created,
                     updated,
                     u.enabled,
                     forename,
                     surname,
                     dob,
                     email,
                     mobile
              FROM users as u
                       LEFT JOIN organizations org ON u.org_id = org.id
                       LEFT JOIN roles r ON u.role = r.code
                  ${filter}),
     counter AS (SELECT CASE WHEN ${offset} = 0 THEN count(*) ELSE NULL END AS count FROM main)
SELECT *
FROM main,
     counter ${orderBy}
OFFSET ${offset} LIMIT ${limit}
```

So basically, it adds column `count` to the rows when variable `${offset}` is 0, and `null` for the rest of time. I've been testing it, and it works well, for a small number of records. Not sure if it is a good solution for 1000+ records...

Any feedback is welcome!

Comment: Since you are already anticipating running the query multiple times anyway (once for each page), efficiency is already a lost cause.

Comment: @jjanes A page is requested only when the client requests it, which in my case requires user input from UI. So it is not a lost cause at all.

Comment: "Efficient count" is a contradiction in terms. [Don't do it.](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/pagination-problem-total-result-count/#total-count)

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe That's like saying - don't use data paging, because data paging in most cases is impossible without record count.

Comment: On the contrary. I recommend to use pagination without a record count. Google does it.